# How to move elasticsearch data directory?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a default installation of Elasticsearch.  It seems to be storing it's data in

```
/var/lib/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/nodes
```

So two questions:

If I want to move my data to another location on the same machine (let's say `/foo/bar` for example)

1) What level in the `/var/lib/elasticsearch` tree do I copy? and

2) What is the relevant setting for path.data in elastisearch.yml?

Comment: In addition to Val's answer, please do make sure that the ownership and group of the new directory is set to elasticsearch or same as in /var/lib/elasticsearch.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

A. You need to move the `elasticsearch` folder, i.e. that's the folder which bears the same name as your `cluster.name` configured in the `elasticsearch.yml` file.

B. You need to modify the `path.data` setting in the `elasticsearch.yml` file to the new folder you've moved the data to.

So, say you are currently using `/var/lib/elasticsearch` and you want to move the data folder to `/foo/bar`, here is what you need to do:

```
> mv /var/lib/elasticsearch /foo/bar
```

Then in `elasticsearch.yml` modify `path.data` to:

```
path.data: /foo/bar
```

You'll end up with your data being stored in `/foo/bar/elasticsearch` instead of `/var/lib/elasticsearch`. Make sure that the elasticsearch process can access your new folder.

Comment: perfect answer!  Thanks!

Comment: @Val once we move the ES data folder to a new path, automatically the new indices would be created there right?

Comment: @Darth_Vader if you move the folder somewhere else, you need to modify the config file as well and ES will pick up the indices from the new location. If you use a new empty location then new indices will be created there

Comment: Yup that's right. It'll not cause any harm to the existing data right? Just being curious.. :)

Comment: Another a small thing, when I'm moving ES and Logstash should not be running right?

Comment: you cannot move the data folder with ES up, so Logstash should be down to.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134145/discussion-between-darth-vader-and-val).

Comment: @Val Should I have to change anything from Kibana as well? Cos I tried running Kibana, but couldn't see the existing ones which I created.

Comment: @Darth_Vader I suggest you create another specific question since we're diverging :-)

Comment: @Val [done](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41888270/how-can-i-safely-move-elasticsearch-indices-to-another-mount-in-linux).

Comment: Here's a nice detailed how-to to do the same thing: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-to-move-data-and-logs-to-new-directory/28382/3

It also mentions how to setup the permissions properly.

Comment: One more thing I noticed: when moving data, the default folder has to be present in order for elasticsearch to start. otherwise it will complain that the default.path.data is unaccessible.

Comment: I want to also change path.logs but it does not seem to have an effect as it fails to start and is still trying /var/log/elastisearch, any ideas?

Answer (score 10):

If you are more cautious about moving your critical data, cp with preserving all attributes (owner, group, timestamp, etc.) can help.

```
cp -r --preserve=all /var/lib/elasticsearch/ /foo/bar/
```

Open elasticsearch.yml and set path.data to new location

```
path.data: /foo/bar/elasticsearch/
```

Restart elasticsearch server. now you can safely remove source data.

```
rm -rf /var/lib/elasticsearch/
```

Comment: the preserve-all is what helped else, there was never ending problem of permissions. - Thanks

Comment: `cp` `preserve` option should be used when migrating the directories. Also one thing to note is the command will only set everything right when it finishes: While it's still copying a directory, and you're running cp as root, the directory will be owned by root. It will only set it to the right permissions when it finishes with this directory.

Ref -- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43605/how-do-i-copy-a-folder-keeping-owners-and-permissions-intact#comment418708_43608

Answer (score 7):

I want to add an annoying problem that I encountered when I was doing @Val's helpful guidance.
After I did:

```
> mv /var/lib/elasticsearch /foo/bar
```

I set the

**path.data: /foo/bar**

But Elasticsearch did not run correctly. For example xpack security (formarly shield) authantication password turned back to its default "changeme". And also when I want to list indices, nothing shown up.
Then I set the

**path.data: /foo/bar/elasticsearch/**

The last slash at the end of the "elasticsearch" is important I think. May be I am confusing but it solved my problem.

Answer (score 6):

Adding on to Val's fine answer...

Maybe starting with ES 5.6 (? didn't research how far back this is true) I moved my data directory to a new location and couldn't get ES to startup.  The index_name.log file showed that ES was looking for the default data directory (/var/lib/elasticsearch), which it couldn't find because I moved it, so startup died.  I made a copy of the now moved directory back to /var/lib/elasticsearch and attempted startup again which failed again.  Log showed that ES did indeed find the default data directory location but also found that there was content so startup was failed.  Final step was to empty /var/lib/elasticsearch and startup succeeded.

In summary for ES 5.6 on RHEL (at least):
1. The default /var/lib/elasticsearch directory must exist
2. The default /var/lib/elasticsearch directory must be empty

Comment: Had same issue also in Ubuntu

Answer (score 2):

Since Elastic Search `6.8`, this practise of manual copying of the data directory has been invalidated; and, it is no longer guaranteed to work seamlessly. Even, if you manage to change the data directory location, and your cluster comes up without errors, the user defined indices created in the older data directory will not be detected. From 6.8, the reliable way to change the data directory path would be to take a snapshot from the older directory, and restore it in the new directory. Detailing the steps that one would perform to achieve this:

1. While still pointed to the older data path, register a snapshot registry and create a snapshot. The snapshot repository should be accessible from all the networks where copy and restore is desired. I have used a NFS path for this purpose. But, multiple other options like S3, Azure, HDFS are available for the snapshot storage. Refer https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.15/snapshots-register-repository.html for details on the other options.

> ```
>  PUT http://localhost:9200/_snapshot/mysnapshotregistry {
>      "type": "fs",
>      "settings": {
>          "location": "/usr/share/elasticsearch/snapshotrepo",
>          "compress": true
>      }  }
> ```

2. Take backup of the older data by creating a snapshot in the registry created in step 1.

> ```
> PUT http://localhost:9200/_snapshot/mysnapshotregistry/snapshot1?wait_for_completion=true
>
> {   "indices": "employee, manager",   
>     "ignore_unavailable": true,
>     "include_global_state": false,   
>     "metadata": {
>     "taken_by": "binita",
>     "taken_because": "testing creation of snapshot"
>     } 
> }
> ```

3. Stop the ElasticSearch service.
4. Update the data directory to the desired path in the `elasticsearch.yml`
   given by : `path.data` field. Remember to give ownership of the updated data directory to uid:gid = `1000:0`. `chown -R 1000:0 <updated data directory>`
5. Start the ElasticSearch service.
6. Check that at this point of time, your cluster only contains the default indices. All user defined indices would be absent.

> GET http://localhost:9200/_cat/indices

7. Register a snapshot repository in the new data directory pointing to the same underlying NFS path referred in step 1.

> ```
>  PUT http://localhost:9200/_snapshot/mysnapshotregistry2 {
>      "type": "fs",
>      "settings": {
>          "location": "/usr/share/elasticsearch/snapshotrepo",
>          "compress": true
>      }  }
> ```

8. List all available snapshots from the registry created in step 7.

> GET http://localhost:9200/_cat/snapshots/mysnapshotregistry2
> `snapshot1` will be present in the response.

9. Restore the snapshot into the updated data directory:

> ```
>  PUT http://localhost:9200/_snapshot/mysnapshotregistry2/snapshot1/_restore {  
>     "indices": "employee",
>     "ignore_unavailable": true,  
>     "include_global_state": false,
>     "index_settings": {
>      "index.number_of_replicas": 0   
>     },   
>     "ignore_index_settings": [
>      "index.refresh_interval"
>
>    ]   }
> ```